# Can I export Quick Favorites from 2.82 to 2.83

Tags: interface, export, quick-favorites

With all the back and forth between 2.82 and 2.83 daily releases, I was wondering if there was a way to export your 2.82 quick favorites menus to use them in the 2.83 beta?

Answer (score 1):

*Quick Favorites* are part of user preferences and saved along them in the preferences file.

Copying this file from one installation to another should bring *Quick Favorites* with it.

Beware that this file saves most Blender settings along with it, so overwriting with an older one may unintentionally change other preferences you may have already configured. It may also cause unforeseen issues when things change between Blender versions, so use with caution and take care to make backups beforehand.

This file is usually saved under `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\<VersionNumber>\config` for Windows OS. After installing a new version you should have two different `<VersionNumber>`, so copy it from the relevant one to the new one.